# Как добавить пустые поля для ввода данных при отстутствии данных?

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

На странице для редактирования прохожу по списку телефонов и вывожу информацию по типу телефона и номеру.

Для типа телефона реализована возможность выбора из раннее введенных типов (мобильный, рабочий и пр.).

Как сделать так, чтобы при отсуствии данных по телефонам были добавлены поля, в которые можно ввести данные?

```
<p th:each="phone,stat:${person.getPhoneNumbers()}">
       Телефон: <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[__${stat.index}__].type" th:list="phoneTypes" th:value="${phone.getType()}" >
        <datalist id="phoneTypes">
            <option th:each="phoneType:${phoneTypes}" th:value="${phoneType}"
                    th:text="${phoneType}"></option>
        </datalist>


       Номер: <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[__${stat.index}__].number"  th:value="${phone.getNumber()}" >
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Поля можно добавлять после проверки на отсутствие данных

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(phone)}">
 <p th:each="phone,stat:${person.getPhoneNumbers()}">
       Телефон: <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[__${stat.index}__].type" th:list="phoneTypes" th:value="${phone.getType()}" >
        <datalist id="phoneTypes">
            <option th:each="phoneType:${phoneTypes}" th:value="${phoneType}"
                    th:text="${phoneType}"></option>
        </datalist>


       Номер: <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[__${stat.index}__].number"  th:value="${phone.getNumber()}" >
 </p>
</div>
<div th:unless="${not #lists.isEmpty(phone)}">
   Телефон: <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[0].type" th:list="phoneTypes">
        <datalist id="phoneTypes">
            <option th:each="phoneType:${phoneTypes}" th:value="${phoneType}"
                    th:text="${phoneType}"></option>
        </datalist>        
   Номер: <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[0].number">
</div>
```